# JQuery Moving and Removing content from Div Based on Checkbox Values

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm attempting to take content from a div that contains an unordered list and has a CSS display: none value (i.e., hidden div), and place certain list elements into placeholder divs for display based on certain values of a checkbox that correspond to the classes of the list elements.

On initial display and when no checkboxes are checked, I want all list elements in the hidden div to show up in the placeholder divs.

When checkbox(es) are checked I want to perform a function that takes all of the selected checked checkbox values and bring from the hidden div to the placeholder divs only the list elements with a class value that corresponds to the checkbox values.  Those list elements in the hidden div without a corresponding checkbox value should not be displayed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="php_hidden_results">
<ul id="vv_bg_results">
    <li class="Sauces_Dips_Spreads Latin">Chili Lime Sour Cream</li>
    <li class="Main_Dish Latin">Carnitas</li>
</ul>

<ul id="vv_content_wrapper_results">
    <li class="Sauces_Dips_Spreads Latin"><div class="vv_content" id="content1">
        <h2><a href="/v1.0/recipes/show_recipe.php?idrecipe=22">Chili Lime Sour Cream</a></h2>
        <div class="vv_content_box">
            <div class='subtitle'>Sauces Dips Spreads: Latin</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Main_Dish Latin"><div class="vv_content" id="content2">
        <h2><a href="/v1.0/recipes/show_recipe.php?idrecipe=21">Slow Cooker Carnitas</a></h2>
        <div class="vv_content_box">
            <div class='subtitle'>Main Dish: Latin</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul> 
</div>

<div id="test">Replace with checked value</div>

<div class="filterContainerBody">              
<b>RECIPE TYPES</b><br />
<div class="horzRule"></div>
<ul class="checkfilter">
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Sauces_Dips_Spreads' />Sauces Dips Spreads</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Main_Dish' />Main Dish</li>                
</ul>
<b>CUISINE TYPES</b><br />
<div class="horzRule"></div>                
<ul class="checkfilter">
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Latin' />Latin</li>                
</ul>
</div><!-- end of filterContainer -->

<div id="vv_bg" class="vv_bg">   
   <ul class="results">
        <li></li>            
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="vv_content_wrapper" class="vv_content_wrapper">
    <ul class="results">
        <li></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#php_hidden_results
{
    display: none;
}

.filterContainerBody
{
    width: 240px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffbb00;
}
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul.checkfilter :checkbox").click(function() {
    var divhidden_bg_li = $('#php_hidden_results ul#vv_bg_results li');
    $(".checkfilter :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        var filtervalue = $(this).val();
        var filterclass = $(divhidden_bg_li).filter(filtervalue);
        var divhidden_bg= $('#php_hidden_results ul#vv_bg_results').children("." + filtervalue);
        $('#vv_bg ul.results').html(divhidden_bg); 
        var divhidden_content = $('#php_hidden_results ul#vv_content_wrapper_results').children("." + filtervalue);
        $('#vv_content_wrapper').html(divhidden_content);                               
    });   
});
});
```

The above jquery does not show all of the list elements on initial page or when no checkboxes are selected, and will retrieve certain list elements from the hidden div on the first check, but becomes unresponsive.  See http://jsfiddle.net/Ayjent/ddsjB/5/

I am aware of hide and show, which I had working fine, except for a placeholder problem in my display that I want to avoid.  See the jsfiddle above with the code (the li elements in the hidden div were formerly in the placeholder divs).  I wanted to avoid AJAX for continuous server calls, but it may be the better solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: okay looks like I can get every list element to display once the checkbox value gets the corresponding list element with that class by changing the .html(divhidden_bg) and .html(divhidden_content) to append.(divhidden_bg) and append.(divhidden_content).  Now to figure out how to get them to only display based on the checked value.  http://jsfiddle.net/Ayjent/ddsjB/8/

Comment: if you add empty() before, $('#vv_bg ul.results').empty().append(divhidden_bg);
you could remove content, but seem to have problem with append

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex, I'll fiddle around with using the empty() function, or detach(), and see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:checkbox').change(
            function(){
        var vv_bg = $('.vv_bg').find('.'+$(this).val()).html();
        var vv_content = $('.vv_content_wrapper').find('.'+$(this).val()).html();
                if ($(this).is(':checked') && (vv_bg != null && vv_content != null)) {
                    $('<li>'+vv_bg+'</li>').attr('class',$(this).val()).appendTo('#result_vv_bg ul');   
            $('<li>'+vv_content+'</li>').attr('class',$(this).val()).appendTo('#result_vv_content_wrapper ul');
                }
                else {
                    $('#result_vv_bg li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').remove();
            $('#result_vv_content_wrapper li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').remove();    
                }
            });     
});
```

Fiddle -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkgWx/)

Comment: Thanks Alex - that definitely works.  I've still got to implement the code into an actual working site, and this may be the better solution.  I'm going to try later today or tomorrow to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I had to totally rework the structure of the jquery function and html to get rid of the hidden div and placeholder div, and used the delegate(), appendTo(), empty(), and detach functions as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="filterContainerBody">              
<b>RECIPE TYPES</b><br />
<div class="horzRule"></div>
<ul class="checkfilter">
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Sauces_Dips_Spreads' />Sauces Dips Spreads</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Main_Dish' />Main Dish</li>                
</ul>
<b>CUISINE TYPES</b><br />
<div class="horzRule"></div>                
<ul class="checkfilter">
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='Latin' />Latin</li>                
</ul>
</div><!-- end of filterContainer -->

<div id="vv_bg" class="vv_bg">   
<ul class="results">
    <li class="Sauces_Dips_Spreads Latin">Chili Lime Sour Cream</li>
    <li class="Main_Dish Latin">Carnitas</li>          
</ul>
</div>

<div id="vv_content_wrapper" class="vv_content_wrapper">
<ul class="results">
    <li class="Sauces_Dips_Spreads Latin"><div class="vv_content" id="content1">
        <h2><a href="/v1.0/recipes/show_recipe.php?idrecipe=22">Chili Lime Sour Cream</a></h2>
        <div class="vv_content_box">
            <div class='subtitle'>Sauces Dips Spreads: Latin</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Main_Dish Latin"><div class="vv_content" id="content2">
        <h2><a href="/v1.0/recipes/show_recipe.php?idrecipe=21">Slow Cooker Carnitas</a></h2>
        <div class="vv_content_box">
            <div class='subtitle'>Main Dish: Latin</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

​
JQUERY:

```
var $lis_bg;
var $lis_content_wrapper;

$('.checkfilter').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {

if (!$lis_bg){ 
    $lis_bg = $('#vv_bg ul.results > li').detach();
    $lis_content_wrapper = $('#vv_content_wrapper ul.results > li').detach();
};
$('#vv_bg ul.results').empty();
$('#vv_content_wrapper ul.results').empty();

if ($('input:checked').length == 0) {
    $lis_bg.appendTo('#vv_bg ul.results');
    $lis_content_wrapper.appendTo('#vv_content_wrapper ul.results');
    $lis_bg = null;
    $lis_content_wrapper = null;
} else {
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(i, chk) {
        if (chk.checked) {
            $lis_bg.filter('.' + $(chk).attr('value')).appendTo('#vv_bg ul.results');
            $lis_content_wrapper.filter('.' + $(chk).attr('value')).appendTo('#vv_content_wrapper ul.results');
        } 
    });

}
});​
```